# Remove duplicate objects with condition

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a list of objects like this:

```
let b = [
  {
    name: "test1", 
    connectedTo: "",
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    connectedTo: "test1.test2.test3"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    connectedTo: "",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    connectedTo: "",
  }
]
```

I want to get elements without duplicates `name` and also if there are duplicates take one without empty `connectedTo`. So from example above the result that I expect is:

```
let result = [
  {
    name: "test1",
    connectedTo: "test1.test2.test3"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    connectedTo: "",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    connectedTo: "",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach utilizing [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
let b = [
  {
    name: "test1", 
    connectedTo: "",
  },
  {
    name: "test1",
    connectedTo: "test1.test2.test3"
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    connectedTo: "",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    connectedTo: "test1.test2",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    connectedTo: "",
  }
];

const result = Object.values(b.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(!acc[cur.name] || !acc[cur.name].connectedTo)
    acc[cur.name] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```